# Update metadata of an asset in Google Earth Engine API with Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, google-earth, google-earth-plugin, google-earth-engine

I want to update the metadata properties for an asset, whether it's an Image or Table/Featured Collection.

I've followed the documentation but it's not updating or giving me any errors...
https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-featurecollection-set

```
let asset = await ee.FeatureCollection(assetId);
let response = await asset.set('property_name', 'property_value')
```

Any ideas how to do this with the Javascript NPM library? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not in the documentation but in the source code I found the following and it works:

```
ee.data.setAssetProperties(assetId, {
  'property_name': "property_value"
}, (response) => {
  console.log(response)
})
```